# EXCEL: Combining two dynamic arrays with multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following is a simplified version of a structured table that I'm using in excel, where values in "Client1/Client1Share/etc." are determined by lookups to other tables:

[image]

From this table I produce two dynamic arrays where each client position is split into a unique record. They are as follows:

[image]
`=INDEX(tblFruit,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblFruit)),XMATCH({"Fruit","ClientCode","Client1","Client1Share"},tblFruit[#Headers]))`

[image]
`=FILTER(INDEX(tblFruit,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblFruit)),XMATCH({"Fruit","ClientCode","Client2","Client2Share"},tblFruit[#Headers])),tblFruit[Client2]<>"")`

I'd like to be able to combine these two dynamic arrays into a single dynamic array of the format:

[image]

Using a solution proposed by a user on the /r/excel subreddit involving TEXTJOIN to create a comma delimited version of the table and then using FILTERXML + INDEX/SEQUENCE to structure this into a dynamic array I was able to solve this issue for my example table. Their solution was as follows:

`=INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,(FILTER(INDEX(tblFruit,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblFruit)),XMATCH({"Fruit","ClientCode","Client2","Client2Share"},tblFruit[#Headers])),tblFruit[Client2]<>"")))&","&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(tblFruit,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblFruit)),XMATCH({"Fruit","ClientCode","Client1","Client1Share"},tblFruit[#Headers]))),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,(FILTER(INDEX(tblFruit,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblFruit)),XMATCH({"Fruit","ClientCode","Client2","Client2Share"},tblFruit[#Headers])),tblFruit[Client2]<>"")))&","&TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX(tblFruit,SEQUENCE(ROWS(tblFruit)),XMATCH({"Fruit","ClientCode","Client1","Client1Share"},tblFruit[#Headers]))),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))/4,4))`

However the real table/dynamic arrays that I'm working with are much larger, with up to 50 columns and between 500-2000 records. This meant that the TEXTJOIN function would return a string that is longer than the 32,767 characters upper limit imposed by excel on a single cell and the formula would return a #VALUE! error.

I was wondering if there are any other solutions to this problem of joining two dynamic arrays, or if there is any way in this example of getting around the character limit? If possible I'd like the solution to be scaleable in the event that the number of records exceeds my estimates here.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thanks. -L.

Comment: Are you open to VBA solutions?

Comment: Have a look at Powerquery

Comment: The same user on /r/excel also recommended powerquery as a better solution. I'll look into it. My intention was to change the data into a format that I could create reports for clients with, and then filter the range as necessary to exclude/include certain records according to certain conditions as needed. If I can do that with power query then that might be the way to go.

Comment: You can certainly create your last table from your first using Power Query. You could probably use PQ to create your last table, with input being the tables you now use to create your first table in your question.